# matches person name in where condition that is coming from url

Tags: php, mysql

i have no id to compare that's why i have to compare with name that is coming from url and name has space but it shows % sign in between of that how to resolve it

```
<a href="'+base+'/library_master/view_books_by_author/'+book_author+'/'+book_category+'" class="btn btn-default">edit</i></a>
```

mysql

```
 SELECT id FROM books WHERE book_author=$book_author AND book_category=$book_category
```

it shows me % in between of book_author in url

Comment: URL decode the value that contains the %. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php 
Show us how you are building the URL in PHP

Comment: will urldecode() match it?  e.g=j roky=j%rocky

Comment: From the manual/link provided..  Decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.

Comment: I guess you are making it to make user friendly URLs. I can suggest you to replace the spaces with `- ` or `_` symbol, and replace the symbol with space when you get it from URL.

Answer (score 0):

% means space between the values so try to remove space in your URL.else if u use get/post method first fetch the value from URL ($_GET[index'] or $_POST['index']).then print answer if it came from % sign use explode(),preg_replace() to remove unwanted characters